# Sharing a TEXT alonsgide with a page text on FB and LINKEDIN?

Tags: facebook, linkedin-api

I've just stumbled upon sharing a text (a hashtag) togeher with a text on Facebook / LinkedIn. Here is hwat I am trying to do (hashtag: #STUFF):

```
<li class="facebook"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=<?php echo '#STUFF'. urlencode(get_the_permalink()); ?>">facebook</a></li>
```

THIS, unfortunately doesn't work (no wonder!)
There is **"Say Something about it"** field on FB. **Can I add a piece of code to the sharing button so that field will contain text** (pretty much like with "subject" for email sending).

I am able to do that with Twitter. Like this:

```
 <li class="twitter"><a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=<?php echo urlencode(get_the_title() . ', #STUFF'); ?>&url=<?php echo urlencode(get_the_permalink()); ?>&original_referer=<?php ?>">twitter</a></li>
```

Comment: no no, I am asking a different thing!
hashtag was just an example. basically I just need to add A PIECE OF TEXT before the site's title and url t share on FB.

Comment: Facebook doesn’t allow that. The user has to input the whole message, and your app is not allowed to pre-fill or modify it in any way.

Comment: thanks! yeah - I ahve figured taht out toio by now =(
what about LinkedIn? looksl liek it is not possible also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I am uncertain about the other services, you can customize the share text on LinkedIn using this format (Note that all of the `{}` placeholder values should be replaced with URL-encoded values):

```
<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url={URL to share}&title={article title}&summary={article summary}&source={your app/website name}">Link text</a>
```

E.g.

```
<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=http://developer.linkedin.com&title=LinkedIn%20Developer%20Network&summary=My%20favorite%20developer%20program&source=LinkedIn">Link text</a>
```

Complete documentation for sharing content can be found here:  https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin

Answer (score 1):

**Facebook**

Using sharer, you can only specify `url`, like so...

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u={url}
```

Source: [**Facebook Sharer Documentation**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/).

BUT, if you register your app, get an app id, and install the Facebook share dialog plugin, then you have virtually unlimited access to specify sharing...

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?app_id={app_id}&display={page_type}&href={url}&redirect_uri={redirect_url}
```

Source: [**Facebook Dialog Documentation**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog).

**LinkedIn**

So, you cannot really specify any `text` when sharing on LinkedIn.  You can only set the `url` param.  But you can set the `og:` tags to show `title`, `image`, etc., as a preview in your share page:

- `<meta property='og:title' content='Title of the article"/>`
- `<meta property='og:image' content='//media.example.com/ 1234567.jpg"/>`
- `<meta property='og:description' content='Description that will show in the preview"/>`
- `<meta property='og:url' content='//www.example.com/URL of the article" />`

Source: [**LinkedIn Developer Docs: Making Your Website Shareable on LinkedIn**](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en).

Verify that you did it right with: the [**LinkedIn Post Inspector**](https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/).

BUT, similarly to Facebook, if you register your app, get an appid, etc., you can use this format fully to your heart's content...

```
"com.linkedin.ugc.ShareContent": {
        "shareCommentary": {
            "text": "Hello World! This is my first Share on LinkedIn!"
        },
        "shareMediaCategory": "NONE"
    }
```

Source: **[Microsoft LinkedIn Documentation: Share on LinkedIn](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin)**.