# Is it possible to add share text as a query string to LinkedIn sharing URL and get it to work with LinkedIn mobile app?

Tags: linkedin-api

The "text" query string works with desktop but on mobile the link opens the LinkedIn mobile application (if it's installed). Is there any way to get this working or is this something LinkedIn doesn't support?
Example:
[https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=http://developer.linkedin.com&title=LinkedIn%20Developer%20Network
&summary=My%20favorite%20developer%20program&source=LinkedIn&text=Test](https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=http://developer.linkedin.com&title=LinkedIn%20Developer%20Network%20&summary=My%20favorite%20developer%20program&source=LinkedIn&text=Test)

Comment: Does this answer help at all?  [StackOverflow: Sharing a TEXT alonsgide with a page text on FB and LINKEDIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62139305/2430549)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the standard LinkedIn docs for **[LinkedIn.com: Making Your Website Shareable on LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en)**, you get the impression that the only things you can control are: the title, the image, the description, and the URL, by means of `og:` tags.

But, looking further, it seems that if you register with the LinkedIn Share API, you can send a request to...

```
POST https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts
```

With a content body like...

```
{
  "author": "urn:li:person:8675309",
  "lifecycleState": "PUBLISHED",
  "specificContent": {
      "com.linkedin.ugc.ShareContent": {
          "shareCommentary": {
              "text": "Hello World! This is my first Share on LinkedIn!"
          },
 }
```

If everything worked out successfully, you'll get a server code of `201 Created`.

Source: [**LinkedIn.com: Consumer Solutions Platform > Integrations > Share on LinkedIn**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/share-on-linkedin?context=linkedin/consumer/context)

So, you *can* prepopulate a full message in LinkedIn.  This will, of course, require that users authenticate their LinkedIn account at your site, and that you register your app.  This is a bit more than just using the simple shareable stuff, but it seems to work!