# Share post on LinkedIn with Android

Tags: android, linkedin-api

I have an app built in android in which I need to share a post on LinkedIn with predefined content that can be image or URL.How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: start with [LinkedIn API](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/rest-api)

Comment: Does this answer help at all? [StackOverflow: Sharing a TEXT alonsgide with a page text on FB and LINKEDIN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62139305/2430549)?

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1 - Share URL**

To share a URL on LinkedIn...

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url={url}
```

Source: [**Official MSD LinkedIn Share Documentation**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/share-plugin)

**Step 2 - Set Image, Title, Description, Etc.**

Set your `og:` tags in the `<head>` block of your HTML, like so...

- `<meta property='og:title' content='Title of the article'/>`
- `<meta property='og:image' content='//media.example.com/ 1234567.jpg'/>`
- `<meta property='og:description' content='Description that will show in the preview'/>`
- `<meta property='og:url' content='//www.example.com/URL of the article' />`

Source: [**LinkedIn Share Documentation: Making Your Website Shareable on LinkedIn**](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en)

**Step 3 - Verify Your Code**

You can use the **[LinkedIn Post Inspector](https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/)** to verify that your site is appearing as expected.  Insert your URL here (`example.com`), not the URL you are going to share with (`linkedin.com?url=example.com`).

If you think you're getting stale, cached results, you can trick the Post Inspector and the Share API by adding `?someFakeParameter=123` to your test URL, which makes it bypass the cache.